# Retrieve MySQL field using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get a field from a mySQL database using PHP
The problem is that in my mysql panel I use this sql code:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTS WHERE TEST_ID=1
```

and I get exactly what I want (I see the row that I want to display)
But if i use this code in PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "psw")  or die("\nConnection Failed\n");

mysql_select_db("mydb")or die("\nDB Failed\n");

$query = "SELECT * FROM TESTS WHERE TEST_ID=1";
$result=mysql_query($query);

echo $result;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

all I get is "Resource ID #3"

why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the $result is a resource which is a link to a result set from mysql. To get the actual data you have to do something like:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($data);
```

You would need to repeat the mysql_fetch_assoc() call for each row you want to retrieve, until it returns false, indicating there are no more rows, which can be done in a while loop like this:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Watch out :

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: I go for PDO. Using it ever since I knew it! :) It's fast and powerfull!

Comment: True indeed, but it's irrelevant to this question. If he would've used MySQLi he would've gotten the same error.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo $row["userid"]; // sample column
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

- [mysql_fetch_assoc example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1):

You have received a MySQL resource instead of the resultset you want. You've only received a pointer to the result.

You have to use functions like `mysql_fetch_object`, `mysql_fetch_assoc`, `mysql_fetch_row` etc to get the wanted resultset. Please check the manual here:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch result in any variable and print that It will work. 
Like this :

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "psw")  or die("\nConnection Failed\n");

mysql_select_db("mydb")or die("\nDB Failed\n");

$query = "SELECT * FROM TESTS WHERE TEST_ID=1";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
print_r($row);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Hope this will help you... :)